# Zookeeper to get lock of Multiple resources

Tags: hdfs, apache-zookeeper

My scenario is as follows:
I have 5 linux machines and I have 10(could be more than this) files in HDFS. My requirement is that a single machine should get lock on one of the file and process it while other machine should not process this file but get lock on another file and process those.
For ex: machine1 - gets lock on file2 and process it
        machine2 - gets lock on file3 and process it
        machine3 - gets lock on file1 and process it

I have written a dummy multithreaded java program to simulate it .But it is not working:

```
public class DistributedLock {

    private final ZooKeeper zk;
    private final String lockBasePath;
    private String lockPath;

    public DistributedLock(ZooKeeper zk, String lockBasePath) {
        this.zk = zk;
        this.lockBasePath = lockBasePath;
    }

    public boolean lock(String lockName) throws IOException {
        try {
            boolean locked = false;
            if(zk.exists(lockBasePath + "/" + lockName, false) == null){
            lockPath = zk.create(lockBasePath + "/" + lockName, null,
                    ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                    CreateMode.EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL);
             if(lockPath != null ){
                 locked =true;
             }
            }
            final Object lock = new Object();

            return locked;
        } catch (KeeperException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    public void unlock() throws IOException {
        try {
            zk.delete(lockPath, -1);
            lockPath = null;
        } catch (KeeperException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

}

public class DistributedLockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new DistributedLockTest().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Process(1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Process(2));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Process(3));
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Process(4));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }

    class Process implements Runnable {

        int id;
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Process(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                fileNames.add("file" + i);
            }
        }

        // @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("machine " + id + " started");
                String resource = "resource";
                String path = "/LockDir";
                ZooKeeper zooKeeper = new ZooKeeper("127.0.0.1", 2181, null);
                if (zooKeeper.exists(path, false) == null) {
                    zooKeeper.create(path, null, ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                            CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
                }
                DistributedLock lock = new DistributedLock(zooKeeper, path);
                String lockedFile;
                for (String fileName : fileNames) {
                    System.out.println("machine " + id + " Acquiring Lock on "+ fileName);
                    boolean locked = lock.lock(fileName);
                    if(locked){
                     System.out.println("machine " + id + "got Lock on "+ fileName);
                     lockedFile = fileName;
                    }
                    else continue;
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                System.out.println("machine " + id + " Releasing Lock");
                lock.unlock();
                System.out.println("machine " + id + " Released Lock");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The output I am getting for this is :

```
machine 1 started
machine 2 started
machine 3 started
machine 4 started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 1got Lock on file1
machine 3got Lock on file1
machine 2got Lock on file1
machine 4got Lock on file1
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 1got Lock on file2
machine 3got Lock on file2
machine 2got Lock on file2
machine 4got Lock on file2
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file3
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file3
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file3
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file3
machine 1got Lock on file3
machine 4got Lock on file3
machine 3got Lock on file3
machine 2got Lock on file3
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file4
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file4
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file4
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file4
machine 4got Lock on file4
machine 2got Lock on file4
machine 3got Lock on file4
machine 1got Lock on file4
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file5
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file5
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file5
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file5
machine 3got Lock on file5
machine 2got Lock on file5
machine 4got Lock on file5
machine 1got Lock on file5
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file6
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file6
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file6
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file6
machine 2got Lock on file6
machine 1got Lock on file6
machine 4got Lock on file6
machine 3got Lock on file6
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file7
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file7
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file7
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file7
machine 4got Lock on file7
machine 2got Lock on file7
machine 1got Lock on file7
machine 3got Lock on file7
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file8
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file8
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file8
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file8
machine 1got Lock on file8
machine 4got Lock on file8
machine 3got Lock on file8
machine 2got Lock on file8
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file9
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file9
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file9
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file9
machine 4got Lock on file9
machine 3got Lock on file9
machine 1got Lock on file9
machine 2got Lock on file9
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file10
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file10
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file10
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file10
machine 2got Lock on file10
machine 4got Lock on file10
machine 1got Lock on file10
machine 3got Lock on file10
machine 4 Releasing Lock
machine 1 Releasing Lock
machine 2 Releasing Lock
machine 3 Releasing Lock
machine 2 Released Lock
machine 1 Released Lock
machine 4 Released Lock
machine 3 Released Lock
```

This shows each thread/machine is trying for lock on each file and gets it. But what i wanted was if a machine doesnt get lock on particular machine it should try for lock on another file and process that.
Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two mistakes in your code, the first one is that you use `CreateMode.EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL` for your lock-nodes. When you probebly want to use `CreateMode.EPHEMERAL`. Sequential is mainly used for queues not for locks, and it will create nodes with names that look something like: `file10000000000123` `file10000000000124` etc etc. Therfore you will never create the node you use to check if the lock is taken.

If you fix that issue you will most likely get a race condition between the threads since they first check if the node exists and then creates it. Making it possible for multiple threads to try and create the same node, because of this my solution looks like this:

```
public class DistributedLock {  
  public static final String _LOCK = "lock";
...
  public boolean lock(String lockName) throws IOException {
    try {
        boolean locked = false;
        synchronized(_LOCK){
          if(zk.exists(lockBasePath + "/" + lockName, false) == null){
            lockPath = zk.create(lockBasePath + "/" + lockName, null,
                    ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                    CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
            if(lockPath != null ){
                locked =true;
            }
          }
        }
        final Object lock = new Object();

        return locked;
...
  }
...
```

and the output looks like this, which is what I assume you want:

```
machine 1 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file1
machine 1 got Lock on file1
machine 3 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 3 got Lock on file2
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 4 Acquiring Lock on file2
machine 2 Acquiring Lock on file3
machine 2 got Lock on file3
...
```

PS: As a side note I would suggest that you use [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org/) instead of writing your own looks for Zookeeper, it's much easier and they've covered most of the edge-cases.

Comment: Thanks .. Its really helpful. Also , as my scenario is to have this program run  on different machine . I will not run into race condition . right?

Comment: It will still be possible, if both machines checks if the node exists at the same time, and then both will try to write. It will be harder to guard against this since a simple syncronized-block won't work. This is why I suggest using Curator, a framework written to handle this type of behavior and a lot more. That being said, the race condition will be less likely and you can handle it with smart use of exceptions.